# Asynctask на каждое изменение EditText Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Имеется EditText, имеется слушатель, подписанный на изменение текста в нём. На каждое изменение требуется осуществлять асинхронный запрос на сервер, причем при новом изменении предыдущий запрос нужно отменить, т.к. имеет смысл только последнее состояние. Есть ли какой-то грамотный способ это реализовать? (Java, Android)/

Comment: Да, это называется RxJava. Вот статья как раз про ваш случай https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/3192/

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.

Comment: @AndrewGrow оформите комментарий в виде ответа

Comment: Слишком заумно там всё рассказывают. Я мало что понял.

Comment: Поговаривают, что отменить выполнение `AsyncTask` нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнение `AsyncTask` можно отменить с помощью метода `cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)`.
[Подробнее об AsyncTask на developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Чтобы отменить `AsyncTask`, надо его где-то хранить (например, в `Activity` или `Fragment`, где вызывается `AsyncTask`). Тогда в слушателе можно сначала отменить `AsyncTask`, а затем снова его запустить.

```
if(myAsyncTask != null) {
    myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
}
...
...
...
myAsyncTask.execute();
```

Кстати, есть хорошая книга, в которой объясняется, как работать с RxJava -  Нуркевич, Кристенсен: Реактивное программирование с использованием RxJava.

В гугле можно найти уроки, в которых объясняется, как отменять `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Я так понял, что в моём случае RxJava - лучшее решение. Спасибо за книгу. Буду изучать.

Comment: @KamoSpertsian можно сделать с помощью AsyncTask, но с RxJava решение будет более красивое.